# Differentiation of a double integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Hoping to get some direction on a problem I've come across.

Given a region D bounded by $x + y = t$ , $x = 0$, $y = 0$ with $t > 0$. Show that

$\frac{d}{dt} $ $ \iint_D f(x,y)dA $ = $ \int_0^t f(t-x,x)dx$

Have started out with a change of variable $x = u-v$ and $y = v$.

Leading to: $(u-v) + v = t$, $u-v = 0$, and $v=0$.

Not sure where to take it from here any help would be welcome, thanks in advance.

Comment: things that come to my mind: $F\left(x,t\right):=f\left(t-x,x\right)$, chain rule, parametrized integrals

Answer (score 0):

> Given a region D : x + y = t , x = 0, y = 0 with t > 0.

That doesn't look right.   Can you check that.   I suspect that you were given $D(t): x+y=t, x\geq 0, y\geq 0$ where $t>0$.

Then everything works when you simply use $x=t-s$ and $y=s$, since you know $0\leq s$, $0\leq t-s$, and $0<t<\infty$, and thus $D(t)\equiv \{(t-s,t): 0\leq s < t \}$ with $0<t<\infty$

$$\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t} \iint\limits_{D(t)} f(x,y)\operatorname d A = \dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t} \int\limits_0^\infty\!\!\int\limits_0^t f(t-s,s)\operatorname d s\operatorname dt$$

Carry on from here.